# How to show/hide current working directory in bash prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

When I use Linux console it shows way to current directory "admin@servername:/home$" or not - just "$".
How to turn on/ off this hint (way to directory)?
Probably it should be changes in file .bashrc in  PS1 = '\u@\h:\w$', but this value in PS1 allready.
Here is code sample from .bashrc:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

What exactly should be done to show/ hide way to current directory? Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Questions about configuring your interactive environment, as opposed to about developing software, are better placed at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for advice, I just start working with Linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look up [Bash prompt special characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html).

As you can see in the list, the current working directory is `\w`, and `\a` is the bell character, so just remove those.